# Value in Cell on Sheet1 Changes Color Gradient in Cell on Sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to piece together this code on my own for a while now and just can't get it to work. 
Basically what I want to do is have a table of values on Sheet1 where I input 1, 1.1, 1.2,... to 5 and have each value in each cell correspond to creating a color gradient in specific cells on Sheet2.

For example, if in Sheet1 B12 I input "1.1" I want Sheet2 B13 to be shaded with a specific color gradient that is slightly different from if Sheet1 B12 were to contain "1.2" and this gradient would vary between 1 and 5.

So far, I think I have figured out how to fill a cell with a gradient based on the value of another cell using With and Case statements. However, I can't figure out how to make the code work between sheets and run automatically as cell values change on Sheet1 the colors change on Sheet2.

```
Private Sub Heatmap()

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B13")) Is Nothing Then
            Select Case Range("B13").Value
              Case 1.1
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
        .Gradient.Degree = 180
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    End With
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
        .Color = RGB(0, 176, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.7)
        .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
        .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
            Case 1.2
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
        .Gradient.Degree = 180
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    End With
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
        .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.3)
        .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
        .Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Select
End If
End Sub
```

I haven't gone past working it out for two cases so I don't end up writing hundreds of lines of code and it doesn't work. Once I know it works for these two cases I can copy it over and over and develop the gradients the way I want so each cell on Sheet2 will have a specific gradient according to the value of its corresponding cell on Sheet1.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: You have to enter the code in the `Worksheet_Change` event of Sheet1

Comment: Have a look at my interim colour code. Not at computer, so afraid can't offer more than the [link](https://github.com/DBartrup-Cook/Excel_VBA/blob/master/GetInterimColours.xls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste the Code in `Sheet1` not in any `Module` or `Thisworkbook`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B13")) Is Nothing Then

            Select Case Range("B13").Value

            Case 1.1

                    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior
                        .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
                        .Gradient.Degree = 180
                        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
                    End With

                    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
                        .Color = RGB(0, 176, 0)
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With

                    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.7)
                        .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With

                    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
                        .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With
            Case 1.2

                    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior
                        .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
                        .Gradient.Degree = 180
                        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
                    End With

                    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
                        .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With

                    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.3)
                        .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With

                    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B12").Interior.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
                        .Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        End With
            End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Assuming that your code works fine, this wil make it run automatically whenever the value on sheet1 changes.

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was that simple. I was over-complicating it way too much. Thank you!